# How to calculate the rating of a laravel post

Tags: php, laravel

I need to calculate the server rating. I have tables `server_user_likes` where `server_id` and `user_id` are stored, server likes from users are stored in it. 1 like = 1 line in `ServerUserLike`. With `server_id` and `user_id` values

```
        Schema::create('server_user_likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('server_id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->index('server_id', 'server_user_likes_server_idx');
            $table->foreign('server_id', 'server_user_likes_server_fk')->on('servers')->references('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Model **ServerUserLike**

```
    public function server()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Server::class);
    }
```

I counted the number of server likes

```
        $ratingCounts = DB::table('server_user_likes')
            ->where('server_id', $server->id)
            ->count();
```

And I counted the total number of likes, all servers

```
        $allRatingCounts = DB::table('server_user_likes')
            ->count();
```

And now I need to somehow calculate the server's rating, the so-called top 10 Subtraction will not help, because servers and users can increase every time

p.s Server is the same as Post.

Comment: Well you will have to tell us what YOU consider that calculation of the server rating

Comment: @RiggsFolly the user puts a like, this like is entered in the ServerUserLike table with data about user_id and server_id. I need to calculate which place in the ranking the server occupies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use this query to get top 10 server/post based on likes.

```
// here I use eloquent with model ServerUserLike

$results = ServerUserLike::query()
  ->select('server_id')
  ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS likes_count')
  ->groupBy('server_id')
  ->orderByDesc('likes_count')
  ->take(10)
  ->get();
```

The result will be list of 10 top servers [server_id, likes_count]

And as requested, this is an example how you can show top 10 in `top_server.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($results as $topServer)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
  <td>{{ $topServer->server_id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $topServer->likes_count }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

`$loop->iteration` will show number starting from 1 to 10.
https://tutsforweb.com/loop-variable-foreach-blade-laravel/

Comment: And how do I now specify which place the N server occupies in blade.php

Comment: $results is collection , you can use foreach loop , i will update my asnwer with example

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just looking for $loop

Comment: glad can help you